# Bind a list collection to each textbox of a Report Viewer document

Tags: reporting-services, report, crystal-reports-2008, reportviewer2008

I am using the Report Viewer 2008, and lets say I have an dataSource that is a `List<Company>`
Where each `Company` have the property `Name`, `Number`, `Address`.
I didn't want to bind the dataSource to a Table, but I would like to make it like an word document, like bellow:

[image]

Each `Prop` is a property of `Company` and each `Value` is a value of that property, and each row of the Table would be one page of the report. (Both are TextBoxes represented in a Report Viewer Document rdlc)

PS: I would change to **Crystal Reports** if necessary.

Comment: Why don't you want to bind the dataset to a table? That would probably be the easiest way to create this results. Have you tried the New Report wizard? You can have certain rows of the table cause page breaks.

Comment: @JamieF it it possible to render the table in a way where the columns are on the horizontal, and each page would correspond to a row of a normal  table ?

Comment: Certainly. The group-per-page option is part of the new report wizard, and then you can add as many rows as you want to the details group: each row can have a different field.